# Problems with scrolling inside a div by links

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to scroll inside a div (for example 150px down or up), but only "down" still works. I also dont know, if "animate" is the right way, it seems to be a bit laggy?

The second plan ist, that the down or up link get opacity 50% when the content inside the div is top, or bottom.

Can anyone help me?

```
     $('.down').click(function () {
    $( ".box" ).animate({
        scrollTop: '+=150px'
    });
});
$('.up').click(function () {
    $( ".box" ).animate({
        scrollBottom: '-=150px'
    });
});
```

Here is my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8y1vc699/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change "scrollBotom" to "scrollTop" for your up function.

Comment: I made you a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/8y1vc699/3/ maybe this can help you a bit more with the second part.